# My Eevee Engine Is Rendering Blank Frames

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

I have been trying to render an animation on Eevee. I've recently gotten a new GPU (RX 6800) to replace my old one (GTX 1050ti). After installation, I would try to render the animation and during the rendering process, there will be times (At random) when these blank, checkerboard images come up which causes the end result file to contain moments where the video is fast and moments where the video is slow.

I have no idea what is causing this, I have looked everywhere I could, but have not found a similar issue that gave a good answer to solve my problem.

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. This is Q&A site run by volunteers, we are not programmers nor in any way associated with the Blender Foundation, decision making nor development process of the software. For bug reports please see [Where to Report a Bug](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1377). If the issue is in or caused by a third party addon, please report it to the addon author instead.